# hacer un insert en c# .net

Tags: c#, .net

Consulta en c#:

```
        string query = "INSERT INTO control (id_control, nombre_cliente, detalle, servicio, fecha_vacunas, total_pagar)" +
            " VALUES('null','" + this.cboNombreCliente.SelectedItem + "','" + this.cboNombreMascota.SelectedItem + "'," +
            "'" + this.txtDetalle.Text + "','" + this.cboServicio.SelectedItem + "'," +
            "','" + this.txtFecha.Text + "'," + this.txtTotalPagar.Text + ")";
```

Base de Datos:

[image: Base de Datos]

Este es el mensaje de error al tratar de insertar los datos:

[image: mensaje de error al ejecutar grabacion de datos]

[image: Pantalla del formulario]

Pantalla del formulario

Comment: Sugerencia: El error también se puede compartir como texto

Comment: Pregunta, los valores ingresados en la consulta, los estás tomando directo de un formulario? Porque ese formato para la fecha no va a funcionar nunca

Comment: Para retirar duda puedes mostrarnos el resultado del **query**, ¿que cadena concatenada forma?.

Comment: si directo del formulario alfabravo antes tenia en la bd la fecha tipo varchar incluso es un trabajo de instituto donde nos dieron libertad de varias cosas

Comment: Al contrario. En la BD siempre es mejor usar date para operar con las fechas más fácil. Tienes es que convertir esa fecha que recibes a formato Date. Serviría ver el formulario para ver cómo es que el usuario pone esa fecha, a ver si se puede obtener mejor y darle formato más fácil. PD. Tomar datos directo del formulario y concatenar el query es la receta perfecta para SQL injection. Cuidado con eso!

Comment: Tu INSERT tiene seis campos en VALUES y estás metiendo siete valores; debes revisar qué es lo que quieres insertar. Así mismo, hazle caso a Kamousagi y quita el null inicial, que el campo es autoimcremental y no necesita recibir nada

Comment: En el caso de id_control que es un campo autoincrementable no es necesario agregarlo, revisa la respuesta de @leandrotuttini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que usar parámetros, no se concatena NUNCA los valores en un string:

```
string connstring = "connection string";    
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring))  
{    
    cn.Open();    

    string query = @"INSERT INTO control (nombre_cliente, detalle, servicio, fecha_vacunas, total_pagar)
                        VALUES(@nombrecliente, @detalle, @servicio, @fechavacunas, @totalpagar)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@nombrecliente", cboNombreCliente.SelectedItem); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@detalle", txtDetalle.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@servicio", cboServicio.SelectedItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@fechavacunas", DateTimePicker1.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@totalpagar", Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalPagar.Text));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
}
```

entonces se respetan los tipos de datos asignando un `DateTime` al parámetro de la fecha.

Comment: Gracias Leandro me sirvio tu codigo muchas gracias de verdad solo agregue el codigo del try catch para grabar o enviar mensaje de error

Answer (score 1):

Usa el control **DateTimePicker**, y obten su valor con **.Value**.

Comment: de hecho antes lo tenia como varchar en la tabla para probar pero ahora al ultimo lo cambie a tipo date para ver que podria ser,acabo de probar con ese convert pero aun asi no me pesco Kamousagi   :(

Comment: Muestra el contenido de **query**, se ve claramente que no puedes guardar el valor **sábado, 04 de mayo de 2019** en un Date, usa un control **DateTimePicker** y dale **Format -> Short**.

Comment: lo cambie a formato short pero aun sigo con el error. y tmbn la manera de rescatar el dato con el convert y aun asi nada

Comment: Obten el valor con **dateTimePicker1.Value**, no use el -**dateTimePicker1.Text**, me dices como te va.

Comment: lo probe pero me sale:

Comment: Excelente, por favor muestra el resultado de la variable **query**, deseo ver como se esta formando el **insert**.

Comment: you have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual bla bla bla,,,....use near '01/03/2018 00:00:00', 5465;' at line 1

Comment: Ese es el error, deseo ver el resultado de **string query = "INSERT INT**, quiero ver la variable **query**, que es lo que esta formando, tal vez esta guardando el valor en un campo erroneo.

Comment: Porfa, o usan el chat, o actualizan la pregunta con lo que han probado.

Comment: Veo que el primer campo es un **Autoincrement**, retira el valor null que envias al inicio **'null','" +**, los campos incrementables no necesitan que se envie algun valor, incluyendo el null.